# QML ListView won't respond on mouse click

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Hi all I have tried several things but I can't make my ListView to response to mouse click.

Here is my code of ListView:

```
 ListView {
         id: listview1
         x: 0
         y: 82
        // width: 574
        // height: 967
         width: window.width
         height: window.height
         visible: true
         keyNavigationWraps: false
         boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragAndOvershootBounds
         opacity: 1
         maximumFlickVelocity: 2500
         anchors.leftMargin: 0
         highlightMoveSpeed: 489
         contentWidth: 0
         preferredHighlightEnd: 2
         spacing: 5
         highlightRangeMode: ListView.NoHighlightRange
         snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
         anchors.bottomMargin: 0
         anchors.rightMargin: 0
         anchors.topMargin: 82
              anchors.fill: parent
              model: myModel
              delegate:Component {
                  //id: contactDelegate
                  Item {
                      property variant myData: model
                      width: 574; height: 90
                      Column {
                          x: 12
                          y: 0
                          width: 562
                          height: 90
                          anchors.rightMargin: 0
                          anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                          anchors.leftMargin: 12
                          anchors.topMargin: 0
                          anchors.fill: parent
                          spacing: 2
                          Text { text: '<b>ID: </b> ' + id_korisnika ; verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop; wrapMode: Text.NoWrap; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; color:"steelblue"; font.family: "Helvetica"; font.pointSize: 10 }
                          Text { text: '<b>Ime: </b> ' + ime_korisnika ; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; color:"steelblue"; font.family: "Helvetica"; font.pointSize: 10 }
                          Text { text: '<b>Prezime: </b> ' + prezime_korisnika; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; color:"steelblue"; font.family: "Helvetica"; font.pointSize: 10 }
                          Text { height: 16; text: '<b>Broj telefona: </b> ' + broj_korisnika ; verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; color:"steelblue"; font.family: "Helvetica"; font.pointSize: 10 }
                          Text { text: '<b>Adresa: </b> ' + adresa_korisnika ; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; color:"steelblue"; font.family: "Helvetica"; font.pointSize: 10 }

                          MouseArea {
                              id: mouse_area1
                              z: 1
                              hoverEnabled: false
                              anchors.fill: parent
                          }
                      }
                      }
              }

              //delegate: contactDelegate
              highlight: Rectangle {color:"black"; radius: 5; opacity: 0.7

              }
              focus: true

          }
```

I have tried to put my code in all areeas but I can't make it work. any suggestion is nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i dont see  onClicked handler code in your MouseArea (mouse_area1). How are you trying to capture/respond the mouse click.

Try following code and see what happens.

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouse_area1
    z: 1
    hoverEnabled: false
    anchors.fill: parent

    onClicked:{
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be working and how do I put this highlight part in onclick handler?

Comment: I am not sure , but i think you need to set **currentIndex**. and also need to set **highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true**

Comment: Hey @user123_456, you should not sign a response as correct answer, if you could not get right and sufficient information. I has same problem. After many research, i found solution and i shared it with you. See my response post.

Comment: To Downvoter, can you altest comment why my answer is down voted ?

Answer (score 11):

See `KeyInterction` sample from QtCreator. There is your answer :)
You can see sample delegate as follow:

**ListViewDelegate:**

```
Item {
    id: container
    width: ListView.view.width; height: 60; anchors.leftMargin: 10; anchors.rightMargin: 10

    Rectangle {
        id: content
        anchors.centerIn: parent; width: container.width - 40; height: container.height - 10
        color: "transparent"
        antialiasing: true
        radius: 10

        Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 3; color: "#91AA9D"; antialiasing: true; radius: 8 }
    }

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: content
        text: "List element " + (index + 1)
        color: "#193441"
        font.pixelSize: 14
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onClicked: {
            container.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
            container.forceActiveFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

The key is `MouseArea` section.
Good luck - S.M.Mousavi

Comment: Where is `index` coming from?

Comment: This is a delegate. The `index` is pre-defined on delegate.

Comment: how does `container` access `ListView`? I make my ListView work using this even though my delegate is in a separate qml file but this still works!

Comment: You can access to the ListView from delegate using `ListView` (for example `ListView.view.width`)